# How can i protect the traffic sent from client to server from Man in the middle tools?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, security, man-in-the-middle

I have a .net web application that authenticates logged in users via webservice, however when sending the web request from the client app, via HttpClient, to the webservice, then Man in the middle tools such as Fiddler can detect the traffic and expose sent request data as in the following form:

POST http://192.xxx.1.xx:8080/login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 192.xxx.1.xx:8080
Content-Length: 59
Expect: 100-continue
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

{"User_ID":"boss","Password":"xxx6xXXlX90="}

Now the problem is even though the password in encrypted, but still malicious users can use this user_id and password values to make requests via tools such as "PostMan" and "Advanced Rest Client" to make requests to the webservice for example CRUD functions they are not authorized to,

Please advise on what is the best practice to prevent such attacks, is there a possible way to send the Web traffic in encrypted form, so that even tools like fiddler can't detect data such as HostName and the JSON sent,

Please advise,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: While the guaranteed way to mitigate a man in the middle attack is using client certificates, you can use client-side (javascript) encryption combined with one time keys (a key which is valid for only one encryption) so that at least the requests cannot be re-played by simple tools like postman etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe change the webservice to use TLS? (http**s**://...)

Comment: Fiddler can decrypt SSL traffic by installing a dummy certificate to the trusted root authorities certificate store and then by creating seemingly valid certificates for all web sites and serving this back to the web browser

Comment: you won't be able to defend against attacks with local access ... at some point your clear text or your key has to be in some memory location

Comment: That's correct. Nothing can prevent an attacker who can run code on your pc. The OP asks for mitigating man in the middle attacks. While using TLS is a must, it alone does not mitigate this attack. Actually, nothing can with certainty. That's why we use second factor authentication and even this cannot help when the customer's cell phone is breached, for example.

Comment: when you run TLS, the chain of trust is what prevents MITM ... as long as the local root certificates on the client are trustworthy, you can check if the cert you get from the server is trustworthy... local access here means the attacker can exactly circumvent this... modify the client local CA root store ... without local access, or either the servers private key or a valid CA private key, any third party between client and server is unable to forge MITM certs as long as the ciphers are not broken ... so... why exactly doesn't TLS migitate MITM?

Comment: OP specifically mentions fiddler, (or we can assume any proxy tool with similar capabilities, running on local machine) and wants to prevent it from displaying the request as clear text. TLS will definitely help where the man is in the middle somewhere on the wire, but still not necessarily. Most financial enterprises, for example, have their inhouse CA's root certificate on all staff computers and use proxies to monitor internet I/O to intercept any confidential information being leaked. This is where client encryption can add a level of security.

Comment: that scenario is not man in the middle ... that is an attacker with local access ... if I can control the client local CA root store, and have the capability to run arbitrary privileged software, it's just a matter of effort ... no matter what you do ... in this scenario you have to assume that one of the communicating parties is not interested in keeping the communication secret, or is actively working against that. All established cryptographical measures regarding secrecy have the assumption that both/all communicating parties have the intention to keep the secret...